# How can I make DHCP enabled wifi from Static IP LAN using Laptop?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan

I have a LAN Connection with Static IP. I want to make a DHCP enabled Wireless Connection using my laptopso that I can use Internet in more than one devices.

Earlier I made the Wireless Connection using Connectify Software but I am not getting **Internet Access** on wifi.

Comment: ICS : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the newer version of [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) and got my problem solved. I just created a **wireless network** using connectify and used my **Static IP Ethernet** as source for internet. The wireless network allowing **internet access** on other laptop with dynamic ip address.